# C++ "'Shape': cannot instantiate abstract class" can't find the source of the problem

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I have the class `Shape` that 5 different classes (in different files) inherit from it.
After overriding all the pure virtual functions in all the different classes I get this error:
`'Shape': cannot instantiate abstract class` and it won't tell me from where the error is.
This is the `Shape` class:

```
#pragma once
#include "Point.h"
#include "Canvas.h"
#include <string>

class Shape 
{
public:
    Shape(const std::string& name, const std::string& type);
    virtual double getArea() const = 0;
    virtual double getPerimeter() const = 0;
    virtual void draw(const Canvas& canvas) = 0;
    virtual void move(const Point& other) = 0; // add the Point to all the points of shape
    void printDetails() const;
    std::string getType() const;
    std::string getName() const;

    virtual void clearDraw(const Canvas& canvas) = 0;

protected:
    std::string _name;
    std::string _type;
};
```

and here is an example of 2 classes that inherit from `Shape`:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
    Point _center;
    double _radius;

public:
    Circle(const Point& center, double radius, const std::string& type, const std::string& name);
    ~Circle();

    const Point& getCenter() const;
    double getRadius() const;

    virtual void draw(const Canvas& canvas);
    virtual void clearDraw(const Canvas& canvas);

    // override functions if need (virtual + pure virtual)
    virtual void move(const Point& other);
    virtual double getArea() const;
    virtual double getPerimeter() const;
};
```

And I suspect the problem is coming from this class, and in this class, I'm keeping the functions pure virtual because from this class other classes inherit too and they need a different implementation:

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include <vector>

class Polygon : public Shape
{
public:
    Polygon(const std::string& type, const std::string& name);
    virtual ~Polygon();

    // override functions if need (virtual + pure virtual)
    virtual void move(const Point& other);
    virtual double getArea() const = 0;
    virtual double getPerimeter() const = 0;
    virtual void draw(const Canvas& canvas) = 0;
    virtual void clearDraw(const Canvas& canvas) = 0;

protected:
    std::vector<Point> _points;
};
```

Here is the part in the code where I think the error might occur:

```
if (optionChosen == 0) // Circle
    {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double radius = 1.0;
        std::string name;

        std::cout << "Please enter X: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cout << "Please enter Y: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> y;

        do
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter radius: " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> radius;
            if (radius < 1)
            {
                std::cout << "Invalid radius... Try again" << std::endl;
            }
            // If radius is invalid this code will run again
        } while (radius < 1);

        std::cout << "Enter the name of the shape: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;

        const Point& center = Point(x, y);
        // Create a new circle and push it to the vector
        Circle circle = Circle::Circle(center, radius, "Circle", name); // Circle inherits from Shape
        _shapes.push_back(circle);
    }
    else if (optionChosen == 1) // Arrow
    {
        double point1[2] = { 0 };
        double point2[2] = { 0 };

        std::string name;

        std::cout << "Enter the X of point number: 1" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point1[0];
        std::cout << "Enter the Y of point number: 1" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point1[1];
        std::cout << "Enter the X of point number: 2" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point2[0];
        std::cout << "Enter the Y of point number: 2" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point2[1];

        std::cout << "Enter the name of the shape: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;

        const Point& Point1 = Point(point1[0], point1[1]);
        const Point& Point2 = Point(point2[0], point2[1]);
        // Create a new arrow and push it to the vector
        Arrow arrow = Arrow::Arrow(Point1, Point2, "Arrow", name); // Arrow inherits from polygon
        _shapes.push_back(arrow);
    }
    else if (optionChosen == 2) // Triangle
    {
        double point1[2] = { 0 };
        double point2[2] = { 0 };
        double point3[2] = { 0 };

        std::string name;

        std::cout << "Enter the X of point number: 1" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point1[0];
        std::cout << "Enter the Y of point number: 1" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point1[1];
        std::cout << "Enter the X of point number: 2" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point2[0];
        std::cout << "Enter the Y of point number: 2" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point2[1];
        std::cout << "Enter the X of point number: 3" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point3[0];
        std::cout << "Enter the Y of point number: 3" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> point3[1];

        std::cout << "Enter the name of the shape: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;

        const Point& Point1 = Point(point1[0], point1[1]);
        const Point& Point2 = Point(point2[0], point2[1]);
        const Point& Point3 = Point(point3[0], point3[1]);
        // Create a new triangle and push it to the vector
        Triangle triangle = Triangle::Triangle(Point1, Point2, Point3, "Triangle", name); // Triangle inherits from Polygon
        _shapes.push_back(triangle);
    }
    else if (optionChosen == 3) // Rectangle
    {
        double topLeftCorner[2] = { 0 };
        double length = 0;
        double width = 0;

        std::string name;

        std::cout << "Enter the X of the left corner: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> topLeftCorner[0];
        std::cout << "Enter the Y of the left corner: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> topLeftCorner[1];
        std::cout << "Please enter the length of the shape: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> length;
        std::cout << "Please enter the width of the shape: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> width;
        std::cout << "Enter the name of the shape: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;

        const Point& point = Point(topLeftCorner[0], topLeftCorner[1]);
        // Create a new rectangle and push it to the vector
        myShapes::Rectangle rectangle = myShapes::Rectangle(point, length, width, "Rectangle", name); // Rectangle inherits from Polygon
        _shapes.push_back(rectangle);
    }
```

If someone could help me find the problem I would be very happy.

Comment: Where are you creating the objects? You didn't post the relevant part where the error actually happens.

Comment: Did you try compiling only the Shape? And after that try to compile only the Polygon. That could give a hint.

Comment: Do you ever try to instantiate a Polygon ? Note that you don't need to re-declare the functions pure virtual in Polygon if you don't implement them. Also note that you can use the [override specifier](v) on functions you override.

Comment: @ChrisMM I have added more code down in the post to maybe understand more

Comment: @0xBlackMirror Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: @prmottajr I have added more code to the post

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes, the `vector` is `std::vector<Shape>`, and It tells me the error occurs in a random file named `xmemory` in line 757, I have never wrote this file.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez I have added more code now, maybe you will understand better :)

Comment: Do you `resize` the vector? Try to remove as much code as possible while still reproducing the error.

Comment: @ChrisMM it doesn't matter whether he resizes or not. `Shape`s can't be stored in that vector. All derivation instances will slice down to `Shape`, which can't exist because it's abstract. A vector of polymorphic derivations must be either by pointer (ideally smart) or reference wraps (with great care to object lifetime).

Comment: Why the Rectangle is inside a namespace and the others don't?

Comment: @ChrisMM No, it does it automatically no?

Comment: @WhozCraig So how can I store objects like this?

Comment: Sorry, yes, WhozCraig is correct, wasn't thinking for a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot store the object `Shape` in a vector, since it contains a pure virtual function. You can store pointers in the vector instead, or smart pointers, and create the child classes appropriately.

```
std::vector<Shape*> _shapes;
//…
_shapes.push_back( new Circle( … ) );
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> _shapes;
//…
_shapes.push_back( std::make_unique<Circle>( center, radius, "Circle", name ) );
```

Also, when using inheritance, I'd recommend using the `override` keyword. So in your Circle class, for example, you would have

```
void move(const Point& other) override;
```

Comment: Tying the lifetime of the objects with the vector would be more in line with the initial intent: use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>` instead of naked pointers.

Comment: Thank you, this actually compiles. But I would have a problem passing there local variables because they would be destroyed when getting out of scope.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Good point. I added the example. Hopefully I wrote it correctly (not testing anything).

Comment: Oh I just wrote about that and you edited, thank you!